# Generating a dataset in python given an equation of distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, normal-distribution

So I have a problem where we are given to generate data from a given PDF p(X).

```
P(X) =  Q1(X)p(x1/l1) + Q2(X)p(x1/l2)

Q1(x),Q2(x) = are given (0.8/0.2 something)
p(x1/l1), p(x1/l2) = are guassian distribution with mean and covariance matrix given
```

I am planning to create a given function that generates me n different samples from p(X).

The function should have the following arguments:

Create_data(dim = 2 (let this be fixed), num_of_sam,mean1[],cov1[],mean2[],cov2[])

This should return me an (N *2) array.